# Segmentation fault before return

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

Why does the following code seg fault before returning:

```
int main()
{
char iD[20];
memset (iD, 0, 20);

char* prefix;
srand (time(NULL) );
int iPrefix = rand()%1000000;

sprintf(prefix, "%i", iPrefix);
int len = strlen(prefix);

char* staticChar = "123456789";

//set prefix into ID
memcpy(iD, prefix, len);
// append static value
memcpy(iD+len, staticChar, 20-len);

cout << "END " << endl;

return 0;
}
```

At the minute, the cout will display, but I get a segmentation fault.

Comment: FWIW, the C language does not have `cout`, so you should remove the `c` tag.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to allocate memory for prefix before calling this:

```
sprintf(prefix, "%i", iPrefix);
```

or you could refactor the code e.g.,

```
snprintf(iD, sizeof(iD), "%i%s", iPrefix, staticChar);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
char* prefix;
//some code

sprintf(prefix, "%i", iPrefix);
```

You forgot to assign some memory to `prefix`.

Answer (score 1):

no memory has been allocated to prefix.
so it can access any memory location which which generates segmentation fault , in simple words.